# Adding Color to Some Select Options

Tags: css, html-select

Apparently this isn't as straight-forward as I had expected but I am trying to add colors to certain options in a select box. The options are actually dynamic but, as that is irrelevant to the question, I'll just post the HTML. I don't really care if the background or just the text color changes but I can't seem to make anything change at all! I am testing in Linux Ubuntu Firefox but will ultimately need it to work on iOS Safari.

In the CSS file:

```css
.ColorRed {
    background: red;
}

.ColorGreen {
    background: green;
}
```

In the form:

```html
<select name="Storage" id="Storage">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="40">SV-COUNTER</option>
    <option value="8">SV-C1-B1</option>
    <option value="9">SV-C1-B2</option>
    <option value="10" class="ColorGreen">SV-C1-B3</option>
    <option value="11" class="ColorRed">SV-C1-B4</option>
    <option value="12">SV-C1-B5</option>
    <option value="13">SV-C1-F1</option>
</select>
```

When classes didn't work, I thought that some other style might be overriding it so tried inline styles but it didn't do anything either.

```html
<select name="Storage" id="Storage">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="40">SV-COUNTER</option>
    <option value="8">SV-C1-B1</option>
    <option value="9">SV-C1-B2</option>
    <option value="10" style="background:green !important;">SV-C1-B3</option>
    <option value="11" style="background:red !important;">SV-C1-B4</option>
    <option value="12">SV-C1-B5</option>
    <option value="13">SV-C1-F1</option>
</select>
```

A screen capture doesn't show the dropdown expanded (it closes itself when I make a screenshot) but when open there is no color in it in spite the debugger console showing color.

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Works fine. What browser are you using? Do you have a life demo?

Comment: You said something about dinamically options?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Firefox but I tried Safari and Opera with the same results. The option list is being generated dynamically from database values but that's nothing to do with the issue and sorry, no live view as this is an Intranet site.

Comment: Could you make a screenshot?

Comment: Nothing to see but I tried to take a screen shot. However, the select closes each time and all I get is a capture the closed selector. If you were able to get it to work, though, maybe something on my system is overwriting it so I'll look into that possibility although I'm not sure where to look! The test page has nothing else on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks normal for me, and it works fine.

**UPDATED**

Seems to me, `select` on different operating systems acts differently. We have tested your example on:

- PC win 10 Chrome - **ok**.
- PC win 10 Firefox - **ok**.
- Mac Chrome - **not okay**.
- Mac Safari - **ok**.
- Mac Firefox - **not okay**.
- Linux Ubuntu Opera - **ok**
- Linux Ubuntu Firefox - **not okay**
- Linux Ubuntu Firefox - (WINE) **ok**
- iOS Firefox - **not okay**
- iOS Opera - **not okay**
- iOS Safari - **not okay**
- iOS MS Edge - **not okay**

It's definitely a **browsers+OS** issue.

To get full control over select box css you can try to use some jquery framework, for example **select2**

https://select2.org/

https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: I don't doubt that you're right but so far I've not found anything. No JavaScript is running at all and any other CSS is called before the form and even then there is nothing in it relating to select boxes or which use the same class tags. Also, I would expect that the inline CSS should work even if something else was interfering! I even ran the HTML form all by itself with nothing else whatsoever and it still doesn't work. Still looking, though, as there must be something that I missed.

Comment: May be, it could be some program on your PS, for example password keeper. Or a browser application. Anything, that affects browsers standard forms, could be possible

Comment: Still looking but so far nothing. No browser plug-ins other than those it comes with. Is there any server configuration that might account for it? I can't think of anything like that myself that could cause this type of mischief.

Comment: The best way is to do a screenshot with the console opened like i suggested. It will help a lot. It's no necessary to make a select active, just inspect the option tag with background. Like on my screenshot.

Comment: I did a screenshot as requested and appended it to the original question but it looks virtually identical to yours other than the lack of color in the select box. The debugger console shows the color but it isn't actually there.

Comment: Interesting! Doesn't look like a standard select an all. What operation system do you use? Look like some OS features. Any other select boxes on other sites looks like than?

Comment: I run Ubuntu Linux but I don't see anything odd about the select box other than the missing colors. It looks like any non-styled select box on mine or other sites. In the meantime I put a test copy on one of my live sites and it works no better there for me so I would be curious if you see the colors. If you do, then it must be something here although what that might be I can't imagine, especially as I also can't see any colors when testing it on my iPad's Safari or Opera browsers. http://www.dlpierson.com/test2.php

Comment: Now that you mention it, the select box looks odd to me too, especially when not opened!  But it looks the same on my iPad as it does on the PC and looks the same whether on my local wired, WiFi or cellular networks.

Comment: I had almost come to the same conclusion before posting the question but was hoping that someone would say I was wrong. Anyway, good answer and good detective work even if it's not what I wanted to hear. I would be happy to accept it but first please add the following to the browser list: `Linux Ubuntu Opera ok`, `Linux Ubuntu Firefox not okay`, `Linux Ubuntu Firefox (WINE) ok`, `iOS Firefox not ok`, `iOS Opera not ok`, `iOS Safari not okay` and `iOS MS Edge not ok`. Also, please correct ***operation system*** to ***operating system***. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for correcting! Just added your list and corrected text. Real useful case! I'm glad I was able to help.